# Delete an item in the list

Tags: jquery, html, list

I must be able to manipulate a list with jquery. I created a list with an element already:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista1").on('click', 'canc', function() {
    $ogg1 = $(this).closest('li');
    $ogg1.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">
  <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  </li>
  <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem2"> Pesce </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I would like to delete an element when the delete key is pressed and the whole list goes up backwards.
How can I do?

Comment: where's your jquery code attempt?

Comment: Did you mean `,'#canc',` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly your `canc` selector is missing the `#` prefix for the `id` selector. Secondly, you're creating duplicate `id` attributes on the `button` elements which is invalid. Instead you should use common classes, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista1").on('click', '.canc', function() {
    $ogg1 = $(this).closest('li');
    $ogg1.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">
  <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem1">Carne</p>
    <button class="mod badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button class="canc badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  </li>
  <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem2">Pesce</p>
    <button class="mod badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button class="canc badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of ids for cancel button and use below code

```
  $(".canc").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
   });

<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

    <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
        <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
        <button  class="badge badge-primary badge-pill canc">X</button>

    </li>

    <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <p id="elem2"> Pesce </p>
        <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
        <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill canc">X</button>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below example,

```js
function fnDelete(obj) {
    obj.closest("li").remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

  <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" onclick="fnDelete(this)">X</button>

  </li>

  <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem2"> Pesce </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" onclick="fnDelete(this)">X</button>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: The OP said "I must be able to manipulate a list with jquery", so removing the current use of jQuery and instead embedding JS in attributes isn't what they're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since, ID is a uniquely identified attribute, I have added **Remove** class for both of the delete buttons. Onclick of delete button I am removing the parent node of the current object. That's all. Note: It's not preferable to use same Id in for multiple controls. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">
  <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill Remove">X</button>
  </li>
  <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem2"> Pesce </p>
    <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill Remove">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could [edit] your answer to add an explanation about why the OP's code doesn't work, and what you've changed to fix it.